# Best way to generate API Key?

Tags: api, access-token, api-key, stripe-payments

#### Use Case

I'm building an iPhone app with a simple signup and login.

When a user signs up/logs in, I want the Ruby (Sinatra) server to generate/fetch and return an access token for that user that the iPhone client can then send with every subsequent request using Basic Authentication over HTTPS.

I'm not yet implementing OAuth 2.0 so that third party apps can access the server. Right now, I'm just building a simple, internal API (for my own, first-party, iPhone app).

#### Example

Basically, I want to generate a secret API key like Stripe's: https://manage.stripe.com/account/apikeys

For example: `sk_test_NMss5Xyp42TnLD9tW9vANWMr`

What's the best way to do that, say in Ruby?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Ruby stdlib provides an entire class of secure random data generators called [`SecureRandom`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html). Whatever you want, you can probably find it there.

Stripe's keys are essentially URL-safe Base64. You can get something very similar like so:

```
require 'securerandom'

p "sk_test_" + SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
```

(Stripe does strip out non-alphanumeric characters, but that's trivial to do with gsub if you don't want hyphens in your keys.)

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a gem called [sssecrets](https://rubygems.org/gems/sssecrets) (for Simple Structured Secrets) to solve this problem.

Sssecrets is a reusable implementation of GitHub's [API token format](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/) (which is also used by [NPM](https://github.blog/2021-09-23-announcing-npms-new-access-token-format/)), and it's designed to make it simple for developers to issue secure secret tokens that are easy to detect when leaked.

Simple Structured Secrets provides a compact format with properties that are optimized for detection with static analysis tools. That makes it possible to automatically detect when secrets are leaked in a codebase using features like [GitHub Secret Scanning](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning) or GitLab Secret Detection.

### Why Use Structured Secrets?

Using a structured format for secrets is really important for security reasons. If you're a developer and your application issues some kind of access tokens (API keys, PATs, etc), you should try to format these in a way that both identifies the string as a secret token and provides insight into its permissions. For bonus points, you should also provide example (dummy) tokens and regexes for them in your documentation.

Here's an example of a bad secret. As of the time of writing, HashiCorp Vault's API access tokens look like this ([ref](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs#authentication)):

`f3b09679-3001-009d-2b80-9c306ab81aa6`

You might think that this is pretty is a pretty easy pattern to search for, but here's the issue: It's just a UUID string.

While random, strings in this format are used in many places for non-sensitive purposes. Meaning that, given a random UUID formatted string, it's impossible to know whether it's a sensitive API credential or a garden-variety identifier for something mundane. In cases like these, secret scanning can't help much.

### What's in a Structured Secret?

Structured secrets have three parts:

- A prefix (2-10 characters, defined by you)
- 30 characters of randomness
- A 6 character checksum

That's it!

Here's the format:

`[prefix]_[randomness][checksum]`

An example Sssecret, with an `org` of `t` and a `type` of `k`, looks like this:

`tk_GNrRoBa1p9nuwm7XrWkrhYUNQ7edOw4GUp8I`

#### Prefix

Token prefixes are a simple and effective method to make tokens identifiable. [Slack](https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types), [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication), [GitHub](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/#identifiable-prefixes), and others have adopted this approach to great effect.

Sssecrets allows you to provide two abbreviated strings, `org` and `type`, which together make up the token prefix. Generally, `org` would be used to specify an overarching identifier (like your company or app), while `type` is intended to identify the token type (i.e., OAuth tokens, refresh tokens, etc) in some way. To maintain a compact and consistent format for Sssecret tokens, `org` and `type` together should not exceed 10 characters in length.

#### Entropy

Simple Structured Secret tokens have an entropy of 178:

`Math.log(((“a”..“z”).to_a + (“A”..“Z”).to_a + (0..9).to_a).length)/Math.log(2) * 30 = 178`

*See the [GitHub blog](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/#token-entropy).*

#### Checksum

The random component of the token is used to calculate a CRC32 checksum. This checksum is encoded in Base62 and padded with leading zeroes to ensure it's always 6 characters in length.

The token checksum can be used as a first-pass validity check. Using these checksums, false positives can be more or less eliminated when a codebase is being scanned for secrets, as fake tokens can be ignored without the need to query a backend or database.

*Note that this library can only check whether a given token is in the correct form and has a valid checksum. To fully determine whether a given token is active, you'll still need to implement your own logic for checking the validity of tokens you've issued.*

*Another note: Because Sssecrets uses the same format as GitHub tokens, you can also perform offline validation of GitHub-issued secrets with `SimpleStructuredSecrets#validate`.*

### Further Reading

You can learn more about GitHub's design process and the properties of this API token format on the [GitHub blog](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/).

Comment: Oh, learnt something here. Quite cool! Thanks for the gem (and the write up).